# Rails Join table not populated after form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, nested-attributes, model-associations

I am trying to set up a join table for categories/video-posts called categorizations. It all seems fine however, when the create video_form is submitted, the join table is not populated. So firstly is there something wrong with my form below? Do I have to do anything else to for it to know the select field is actually for that table?

```
    video_posts/_form.html.erb

    <%= form_for('video_post', url: video_posts_path) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :video_title, placeholder: "Video Title"  %>
      <%= f.select :id, Category.all.collect { |c| [c.category_name, c.id] }, {:include_blank => true} %>
      <%= f.text_area :video_description, placeholder: "Description" %>
      <%= f.text_field :video_url, placeholder: "URL" %>
      <%= f.submit "Post", class: "submit" %>
    <% end %>
```

Below are my models.

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :categories
      belongs_to :video_posts
    end

    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :category_name

      has_many :categorizations
      has_many :video_posts, :through => :categorizations

    end


    class VideoPost < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
      has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

    end
```

Here is the create function.

```
  def create
    post_paginate
    @video_post = current_user.video_posts.build(params[:video_post])
    if @video_post.save
      flash[:success] = "Video posted!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:success] = "Errors found! Please try again."
      index
      render :index
    end 
  end
```

Many thanks everyone.

Comment: your belongs_to association should be singular. belongs_to :category and belongs_to :video_post .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still no luck. Anyone else have any suggestions? Really struggling with this as there are no errors, I haven no idea what's going wrong.